# GeForce GTX 760: Unsupported Graphics Card or Driver

Tags: opengl

I recently installed Blender on my desktop to dip my feet into 3D modeling and printing.

The computer has an AMD A10-5800K CPU with integrated graphics, which does not support OpenGL. I recieved the “Open GL 3.3” error when trying to run blender.

I then salvaged a GeForce GTX 760 from another computer and installed it, and installed the newest drivers for the card. However, even though the GTX 760 supports OpenGL up to 4.3, I’m still receiving the 'Unsupported Graphics Card or Driver' error with the “Support for OpenGL 3.3 or Higher is required”.

I’m not sure if Blender is still trying to use my AMD integrated card. I have attempted uninstalling and reinstalling Blender after installing the GTX 760.  I've also disabled the integrated graphics in my BIOS.

Windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: The GTX 760 is supported and should work. The most recent driver is 442.59 (WHQL) for Windows. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that in the main post.

Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to figure it out.

Had to go into my BIOS and disable the integrated graphics (again), then completely uninstall the AMD Catalytst Control Center, then uninstall and reinstall Blender again.